# Missing "Prevent App Nap" button on app

Tags: macos, app-nap

I have an app for which I want to prevent app nap.  However, it does not have a "Prevent App Nap" checkbox.  What can I do?

Missing app nap prevention:
[image: Missing App Nap]

Has app nap prevention:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can disable App Nap for a particular Application by going to **Terminal.app** and typing:

`defaults write <app domain name> NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES`

Being the *`<app domain name>`* the application's name and its company's, with the following format: **com.companyname.appname**

Comment: Cool, I had used this and it didn't work at first.  Restarting the program seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I use `mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier /path/to/my.app` to determine the `<app domain name>`.