# How to disable App Nap in 10.13.6?

Tags: power-management, app-nap

I'm trying to disable App Nap for Chrome, but I can't find the checkbox anymore. Anyone know how to disable App Nap for a specific app in 10.13.6?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not all ap's have the App nap capability.

If you do not see it in the Get Info window it does not have it.

However you can enable it system wide with following in Terminal.

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES
```

Comment: You're right. Activity Monitor shows my Chrome doesn't have App Nap. However, if I have Chrome in the background repeatedly loading a page, the CPU utilisation is much less than if it was on the foreground. Is that not App Nap effect?

Comment: You are right, it is some sort of App Nap effect, it is priority. If a app is in background it receives less CPU resources (lower priority).

Comment: Is there some way to increase the priority of a background app? Right now I have to show a bit of Chrome in order for it to use the CPU fully.

Comment: good question, post it as new question so we can discuss it there. This one should be closed as done.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. Photoshop shows it uses App Nap in Activity Monitor, yes has no checkbox in Get Info. Same for Apple Mail. I've previously had to disable it for other apps which did this too - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121386/missing-prevent-app-nap-button-on-app